# alert after edit in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am implementing a simple insert and edit using ajax however on the edit it is not displaying the alert and while insertion it is telling undefined index despite my field names are as in my database

**edit.php**

```
<?php
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error()); mysqli_select_db($connect,'elearning') or die ('database not found: '.mysqli_error()); 
    $id = $_POST["pageID"]; 
    $text = $_POST["text"]; 
    $column_name = $_POST["column_name"];
    $sql = "UPDATE page SET ".$column_name."='".$text."' WHERE pageID='".$id."'"; 
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) { echo 'Data Updated'; } 
?>
```

**page.php**

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function fetch_data() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "select.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#live_data').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
    fetch_data();
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_add', function() {
      var cid = $('#cid').text();
      var name = $('#name').text();
      var icon = $('#icon').text();
      var src = $('#src').text();
      var hint = $('#hint').text();
      var category = $('#category').text();

      $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          cid: cid,
          name: name,
          icon: icon,
          src: src,
          hint: hint,
          category: category
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
          fetch_data();
        }
      })
    });

    function edit_data(id, text, column_name) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "edit.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          pageID: id,
          text: text,
          column_name: column_name
        },
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.btn_delete', function() {
      var id = $(this).data("id7");
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?")) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "delete.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            pageID: id
          },
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            fetch_data();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: for the undefined index error try a var_dump($_POST) in edit.php to see what is in there. Not showing the alert will be a follow-up error (because js cant parse the error received from php)

Comment: is the edit success? if its not try to give an else part for the if in edit .

Comment: Also check each and every variable by alerting before sending ajax .